# Get a list of tables and their fields from the database

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I need to get a list of tables and their fields from a certain database.

As a result, I would like to obtain the following command:

show tables + show table stats

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try

Comment: `SHOW TABLES` is supported... https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_show.html